# i need help creating a menu in python

Tags: python

i am trying to create a numbered menu in python and im coming across an error message stating "unexpected EOF while parsing" im not sure what to do, can anyone help?

```
menu = 0
menu = int(input("pick an option:\n"
                 "1 print all records in system:\n"
                 "2 print employee details:\n"
                 "3 print total salary:\n"
                 "4 print average salary:\n"
                 "5 add new employee to system:\n"
                  "6 staff positions:\n"
                  "7 salarys over £30,000:\n"
                 "8 exit:\n\n"
                 "Option selected: ")
```

Comment: Count your parentheses...

Comment: Please, format your question better. The way you format your code now, it is unreadable. Edit your question, select your code, and click "format as code".

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a parentheses in the end:

```
menu = 0
menu = int(input("""\
pick an option:
1 print all records in system:
2 print employee details:
3 print total salary:
4 print average salary:
5 add new employee to system:
6 staff positions:
7 salarys over £30,000:
8 exit:
Option selected: """)) # here
```

This will work.

Comment: i didnt even notice been up all night super tired lol thank you

Comment: im trying to create a sort of management system  will i need to loop this menu ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another, more clear and flexible version of the menu rendering. In the version bellow, you'll not get ValueError if user inputs non-digit character. You're free to change and extend anything you don't like.

```
# Use OrderedDict or a list, if you're compiling on Python 3.5 or older
menu_items = {
    "1": "Print all records in system:",
    "2": "Print employee details:",
    "3": "Print total salary:",
    "4": "Print average salary:",
    "5": "Add new employee to system:",
    "6": "Staff positions:",
    "7": "Salarys over £30,000:",
    "8": "Exit:"
}

option = None

print("Pick an option\n")

while True:
    print('\n'.join(["{} {}".format(idx, menu_item)
                     for idx, menu_item in menu_items.items()]))

    option = input("\nOption selected: ")

    if option not in menu_items:
        print("Invalid option. Try Again")
    else:
        break

print("Do something with option {}".format(option))  # now you can even cast option to int without any error
```